# Do not get how this kind of return statement works

Tags: javascript

I just can not wrap my head around on how this return function works:

```
   var Object = (function() {

        function init() {       
            console.log('init');
        }

        return { init : init };

    })();
```

I understand that it returns an object, but why two "init"'s are used in the return statement. Is it possible to set this differently to make it more readable? Any more resources where I could read more about this?

Thank you.

Comment: The property 'init' is set to the value of 'init'.  That's as readable as its going to get.  Look up some basic js object tutorials.

Comment: You can do: http://jsfiddle.net/X5QSF/

Comment: Look for "JavaScript module pattern"

Comment: whatever your purpose is, that's a very bad example to learn.

Comment: It allows you to name your internal functions differently from how they are called externally. So you can use readable function names internally that may be already in use in the external scope.

Comment: @abhitalks It might be helpful for you to explain why you think that, and reference material that suggests a better approach.

Comment: @RobBaillie: (1) readability: using the same "init" everywhere is not a good idea to start learning patterns. at least start with different names. (2) "var Object =": again, this is an innovative way to confuse a newbie.

Comment: I think you have to learn about object literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects.

Comment: @RobBaillie: Reference Material = http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: @abhitalks So your point is *not* that the pattern is bad, but rather that the **names used for the object and method are confusing**.  That seems fair enough, and much clearer now that you've explained your position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are defining the function 'init', then you need to declare the object structure and set it to the member variable named init.

You can avoid the doubling up, by removing the variable:

```
var Object = (function() {

    return { init : function() {
                      console.log('init');
                    }
           };

})();
```

But I wouldn't suggest that's more readable.

In addition, you *can*, if the object declaration doesn't include anything that needs to be executed immediately, remove the outer "function".

```
var Object = { init : function() {
                      console.log('init');
                    }
             };
```